# How to force Qt updating/repaiting a hidden QWidget for video capturing?

Tags: qt, gstreamer, x11, video-capture

I want to capture (recording a video) of a QWidget. For capturing the widget I use the given window ID and gstreamer. However when the widget is hidden, the capturing process stopps. It seems that there isnt any data from the widget.
When the widget becomes visible again, the capturing  resumes.

I tried to keep running QWidget update/repait on the hidden widget. 
I also tried to override isVisible() and isHidden() methods of the QWidget. Still no image when the widget is hidden.

Could it be a Qt related issue, or is it X11 related?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call [`render`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render) on the QWidget directly while passing in your own [`QPaintDevice`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html#QPaintDevice). You could then pass the pixel data over a pipe or something into Gstreamer.